# unable to find the gpio directories in beaglebone black rev5 cd /sys/class

Tags: beagleboneblack

by using yocto i made the beagle bone black but i unable to find the GPIO directories under cd /sys/class/

how to configure the GPIO in beagle bone black

We are tried in many ways like tried to add in Recepies and .bsp also all these things are not working